# RoR STI Single of each type for every parent model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, single-table-inheritance

Im trying to validate the count of models that inherit from Parent model and keep them unique.

So i have

```
User has_many :parents
Parent belongs_to :user
```

Also I'm using single table inheritance for this , so:

```
rails g model Type1Parent --parent=Parent
```

overall i have 3 types , so Type1Parent,Type2Parent,Type3Parent.

Every user *must* have only *one* of each type, so for example

```
type1parent = user.type1parents.new
type1parent.save #=> OK!
```

but if i try do this again

```
type1parent = user.type1parents.new 
type1parent.save #=> Error: User already has a type1parents
```

but also be able to create a *type2parent* for the same user.

So , how can i validate the single existence of each type for every user?

Comment: You can add a uniqueness validation on the User model, then make the relation parent to user use `autosave` (so it will trigger User's validations). I would also strongly recommend to create a unique index on `(type, user_id)` of the `parents` table so that if you ever forgot to double-check this uniqueness at some point, the DB will still ensure this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this scoped uniqueness validation to your Parent model:

`validates :type, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }`

Also as suggested by @MrYoshiji add a unique index on `type, user_id` on the `parents` table

Comment: works great, thanks :), could you maybe elaborate on the part @MrYoshiji mentioned?